# How to check with tcl if MySQL Server online

Tags: mysql, tcl

I have a Tcl Script that connects to a mysql DB running on a other server.
Now the script terminates if i reboot the other server.

Is there a way of checking if the server or better the mysql service is running, before connecting?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check if any service is running is to connect to it and ask it to do something trivial (usually either through logging in or doing some kind of no-op). If that fails, the service is down, and if it succeeds, you've got a connection you can use (well, for a while).

The `catch` command can trap issues coming out of a command. It gives a 0 result if the command succeeds and a 1 result if the command fails. (There are other codes for rarer situations, such as a `return`, `break` or `continue` which work in Tcl by using a special exception. You shouldn't get those from a command to connect to a DB!) Thus, you can do this:

```
if {[catch {command-to-connect to-the-database}]} {
    # It went wrong...
}
```

This is all following the general principle of asking for forgiveness instead of asking for permission.

Comment: Thanks, this is working great for the MySQL part of the script, i would also like to do this for the SSH Connection, but it doesn't seem to work there (Command: spanw ssh admin@10.10.10.1) Thanks